# Vuex WebStorm autocompletion not possible with commit dispatch

Tags: autocomplete, webstorm, vuex

I am quite unhappy with the restrictions that the commit dispatch system of vuex impost on IDEs.

WebStorm does not seem to be able to link the literals with the corresponding store actions.

Do you just live with the fact that there is practically no autocomplete and resolution support using vuex? This actually makes me considering to just use ES2017 classes for my state management rather than vuex :(